# xCode 6 constrains for ios 7 and 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, position

I'm struggling to get my constraints working for both ios 7 and 8 in xcode 6. My app is just a webview that should take up the whole screen and not appear under the status bar.

My problem is that it only displays correctly in either 7 or 8, but never both at once. Depending on how I adjust my horizontal constraints it's either too big for the ios7 screen and fits the 8, or too small on 8 and fits 7. Here's the issue and constrains I have set up:

*Edit: I think maybe my superview is positioned incorrectly, since my constraints are relative to the super view. I just can't figure out what would be wrong with it.

ios7 fits
[image: ios7 fits]
too small on ios8 (green background is the parent UIView)
[image: too small on ios8 (green background is the parent UIView)]
20point top constraint to move the view below the status bar
[image: 20point top constraint to move the view below the status bar]
0 side constraint so it resizes on orientation change
[image: 0 side constraint so it resizes on orientation change]
0 side constraint so it resizes on orientation change
[image: 0 side constraint so it resizes on orientation change]
0 bottom constraint so the view isn't pushed below the bottom of the screen
[image: 0 bottom constraint so the view isn't pushed below the bottom of the screen]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pin this webView like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLJsf.png)

Comment: Thanks for replying. With these constraints I can still see green on the edges on ios8 (not as much green as before), but the app is just slightly cut off in ios7.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there were constraints on the parent view that I had the webview in. They did not show up in the left nav like the webview constraints did so I was not aware they were there. In the right inspector panel click on the ruler icon with the view selected and you'll see the constrains. After removing those it was just a matter of tweaking the constraints on the webview to align things properly.